# Angular 2 Router V3 : No provider exception

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I am migrating the angular router component from deprecated beta to V3 alpa 0.7.

I have setup my `main.ts` as below

```
import {bootstrap}    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {AppComponent} from './component/app.component';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/http';
import {HttpService} from '../common/service/http.service';
import {enableProdMode} from '@angular/core';
import {disableDeprecatedForms, provideForms} from '@angular/forms';
import {APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from '../routes/auth.routes';

enableProdMode();

bootstrap(AppComponent,[
APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
HTTP_PROVIDERS,
HttpService,
disableDeprecatedForms(),
provideForms()
]).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

And `auth.routes.ts` is as below

```
import { provideRouter,RouterConfig } from '@angular/router';

//Import components
import {LoginComponent} from '../auth/component/login.component';
import {LogoutComponent} from '../auth/component/logout.component';
import {RegisterComponent} from '../auth/component/register.component';
import {ForgotpasswordComponent} from '../auth/component   /forgotpass.component';
import {ResetpasswordComponent} from '../auth/component/resetpass.component';

export const routes: RouterConfig = [
{path:'user', redirectTo: '/user/login', terminal: true},
{path:'user/login', component: LoginComponent},
{path:'user/logout', component: LogoutComponent},
{path:'user/register', component: RegisterComponent},
{path:'user/register/admin', component: RegisterComponent},
{path:'user/register/librarytrial', component: RegisterComponent},
{path:'user/forgotpass', component: ForgotpasswordComponent},
{path:'user/forgotpass/:reset_code', component: ResetpasswordComponent}
];

export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
provideRouter(routes)
];
```

This should work but for some reason it produces following exception:

```
platform-browser.umd.js:2311 Error: Uncaught (in promise): No provider for Router!
at l (zone.min.js:1)
at zone.min.js:1
at e.invoke (zone.min.js:1)
at Object.onInvoke (core.umd.js:9004)
at e.invoke (zone.min.js:1)
at e.run (zone.min.js:1)
at zone.min.js:1
at e.invokeTask (zone.min.js:1)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.umd.js:8995)
at e.invokeTask (zone.min.js:1)
```

The network calls show that it takes me to Login component when i enter the path `user` as it should but fails after loading the template with the above error.

Here is a short version of the login component

```
import {Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder,Validators,FormControl,FormGroup,REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/forms';
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Router, ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import {ConfigService} from '../../common/service/config.service';
import {AuthService} from '../service/auth.service';

import {Growl} from 'primeng/primeng';
import {Message} from 'primeng/primeng';

@Component({
    selector: 'login',
    templateUrl: ConfigService.BASE_URL+'app/auth/views/login.ejs',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES,Growl],
    providers:[AuthService,FormBuilder]
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit{

...

constructor(private _form_builder: FormBuilder, private _auth_service:AuthService, private _router:Router,private _route:ActivatedRoute){

    ...
}

ngOnInit(){

    this._route.params.subscribe(params=>{

        this.redirect_to = params['redirect_to'];

    });

}

}
```

I have also verified that the `router-outlet` exists in the main component.
What am i missing?

Answer (score 4):

One cause for this error I experienced during a recent migration is a component is still importing @angular/router-deprecated. Check that your app component or any other components nested with login are calling router-deprecated and, if so, replace with @angular/router.

Comment: This is exactly my case. After removing all router-deprecated, it works!